# Process individual Kafka topic messages to multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I am reading a CSV file from SFTP Connector to Kafka topic ‘Topic1’.
Each record contains a number of columns which need to be stored into different tables in MySql database.
For example:
Each message can look like this
Col1 , Col2, Col3, Col4
I would like to

1. Insert/Update Col1 and Col2 in Table1.

   : Table1 columns - Id, Col1 , Col2, Tbl2Id
2. Insert/Update Col3 and Col4 in Table2.

   : Table2 columns - Id, Col3 , Col4

The Id fields in each table are auto generated during insertion.  But for update cases I need to refer to ‘Col1’ to get Id value.

Using MySQLCDC connector, I can sync Table1 and Table2 data in my Kafka topics and can refer in KsqlDB

My question is :
Is it possible to use KsqlDB to process each receiving message in topic so that I can separate and put them into different topics and can use Sink Connectors to write to MySql tables.

Comment: If I understood your question, yes, ksql can select individual fields and create new topics. Did you try anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck in figuring out how to make updates to MySQL tables. The CSV files I read will not contain the Id’s of the actual records in tables. I need to refer to one unique column to get the corresponding Id’s (if exist) and then add to the new topics so that an Update can happen using connector.
When I create new topics separating fields, how do I retrieve the Id’s from the MySQL Tables in KsqlDB (for update case).
Can a Join between CDC Connector table topic and the original topic  help me to get the Id’s?

Comment: Ksql can join Streams/tables, yes.

Comment: Could you please point me to any sample (or similar) usecase article/link done to refer if you have. I couldn't find one so far yet for my update case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your exact problem. You can refer to the [KSQL documentation on joins](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/joins/join-streams-and-tables/). You would first `CREATE TABLE` from the CDC topic that has the IDs, then produce the CSV data into another topic and `CREATE STREAM` for it, then `JOIN` the two while doing `SELECT col1, col2`, for example, but you will need some _other_ common lookup field to actually do the join, if your CSV doesn't have IDs. Once the data is joined, it creates a new topic, and you would use that to write to the Sink connector